# command prompt color glitched

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, color-scheme

my command prompt was working just fine yesterday , today when i opened cmd its color was changed to light blue , i tried changing defaults but it didn't work , i tried `color 07` it worked but its temporary and when i restart its color remains light blue so is there any way to fix this thing , i am attaching screenshot of settings below
[image]

yes i read an answer suggesting editing color in register , i looked into that but "command processor" is missing in my regedit , screenshot attached below
[image]

Comment: have you tried change in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor ? [link](https://superuser.com/questions/429230/how-did-i-change-color-scheme-of-command-prompt)

Comment: i looked into that but can't find "command processor in registry editor , wait i will attach screenshot of that too @Inga

Comment: paste this to the regedit- > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor

Comment: or search "Command Processor" in the registries

Comment: nothing happens , windows "pings error sound" @Inga

Comment: got it inside Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor

Comment: i changed defaultColor under "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor" but when i launch cmd again , color is same that sky blue @Inga

Comment: if you changed the value you may need to restart

Comment: Make sure "Use Separate Background" in the "Terminal" tab is disabled.

Comment: There should be no reason whatsover for changing the value within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` for this, the key you need, should be in your registry by default. Something or someone has removed it. Just add the default key information back where it should be, reboot your PC, and upon boot, check the key and content is still there. _(it may be worth rebooting and checking a few times just to be sure)_.

Comment: You can add the lines back to your registry using the following `4` lines at the Command Prompt: **1.** `%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V CompletionChar /T REG_DWORD /D 9 /F 1> NUL`, **2.** `%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V DefaultColor /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1> NUL`, **3.** `%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V EnableExtensions /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F 1> NUL`, and **4.** `%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V PathCompletionChar /T REG_DWORD /D 9 /F 1> NUL`.

Comment: Thanks @Compo , this worked for me , may you write it in an answer so that i can accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key you show as non-existent should be in your registry. Something or someone has removed it, either maliciously, accidentally, or due to a lack of understanding its necessity.

You can simply add the information back where it should be. The simplest way to do that is to open a Command Prompt window, and copy then paste each of these lines, one at a time into it, pressing the enter key after each paste:

```cmd
%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V CompletionChar /T REG_DWORD /D 9 /F 1> NUL
```

```cmd
%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V DefaultColor /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1> NUL
```

```cmd
%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V EnableExtensions /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F 1> NUL
```

```cmd
%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V PathCompletionChar /T REG_DWORD /D 9 /F 1> NUL
```

After you have done that, just to be sure that it wasn't malicious behavior, reboot your PC, and upon boot, check the key is still there. *(it may be worth rebooting and checking a few times just to be sure)*.

You can check if the key still exists by opening a Command Prompt window and entering the following:

```cmd
%__AppDir__%reg.exe Query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor">NUL 2>&1&&(Echo Key exists)||Echo Key not found
```

If you receive back a `Key not found` message, you should check your PC for malware.